# PHP Txt dns doesn't give new data

Tags: php, dns, txt

I am trying to get a txt DNS record. I have added it to a site but after some time it still doesn't display it. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
$checkDomain = "example.com";
$domainKey = "testkey"; //These data are just for show. I know it doesn't exists on this domain

$dnsArray = dns_get_record($checkDomain, DNS_TXT);

foreach ($dnsArray as $dns) {
    if ($dns['type'] == "TXT") { // extra check, just incase...
        if ($dns['txt'] == "$domainKey") {
            //domain contains this DNS record
            echo 'true';
        } else {
            //something is wrong...
            echo 'false';
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to get DNS_ANY data I receive the following error:

`Warning: dns_get_record(): A temporary server error occurred.`

But when I try to get DNS_TXT I receive the following data:

```
  [0]=> // Note that this is not the new TXT record I am searching for
  array(6) {
    ["host"]=>
    string(28) "site"
    ["class"]=>
    string(2) "IN"
    ["ttl"]=>
    int(300)
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "TXT"
    ["txt"]=>
    string(38) "v=spf1 include:_spf.transip.email ~all"
    ["entries"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(38) "v=spf1 include:_spf.transip.email ~all"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What _does_ come back in your `$dnsArray`? What about if you use `DNS_ANY`?

Comment: I receive an error. I have updated the question with the error

Comment: Wdym by "sometime"? DNS records take some time to propagate to all DNS servers. You can try to specify the DNS servers yourself as that functions seems to accept that as the third parameter. Otherwise you're probably relying on the resolver of the underlying OS.

Comment: I read that sometimes firewalls will block `DNS_ANY` requests, so maybe that's why you get that error.